# SQL statement for comparing actual products and plan products

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need some helps for writing SQL statements to compare count of  actual  products  and plan by like below

2 Input tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_PLAN
(
    PRODUCT  NVARCHAR(50),
    START_TIME  DATETIME,
    END_TIME  DATETIME,
    PLANT_QTY INT
)

insert into PRODUCT_PLAN values ('PRODUCT1','2015-05-12 06:00:00','2015-05-12 07:00:00',5)
insert into PRODUCT_PLAN values ('PRODUCT1','2015-05-12 07:00:00','2015-05-12 08:00:00',3)


CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_ACTUAL_DETAIL(PRODUCT NVARCHAR(50), WORKING_TIME DATETIME)

INSERT INTO PRODUCT_ACTUAL_DETAIL VALUES ('PRODUCT1','2015-05-12 06:01:00')

INSERT INTO PRODUCT_ACTUAL_DETAIL VALUES ('PRODUCT1','2015-05-12 06:02:00')

INSERT INTO PRODUCT_ACTUAL_DETAIL VALUES ('PRODUCT1','2015-05-12 06:03:00')

INSERT INTO PRODUCT_ACTUAL_DETAIL VALUES ('PRODUCT1','2015-05-12 07:05:00')

INSERT INTO PRODUCT_ACTUAL_DETAIL VALUES ('PRODUCT1','2015-05-12 07:10:00')



PRODUCT     START_TIME      END_TIME    PLAN    ACTUAL

PRODUCT1    2015-05-12 06:00:00 2015-05-12 07:00:00 5   3

PRODUCT1    2015-05-12 07:00:00 2015-05-12 08:00:00 3   2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  PP.PRODUCT  
  ,PP.START_TIME 
  ,PP.END_TIME  
  ,PP.PLANT_QTY AS PLANED 
  ,COUNT(PAD.WORKING_TIME) AS ACTUAL
FROM
PRODUCT_PLAN AS PP
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_ACTUAL_DETAIL AS PAD
    ON PP.PRODUCT = PAD.PRODUCT
    AND PP.START_TIME<=PAD.WORKING_TIME
    AND PP.END_TIME>=PAD.WORKING_TIME
GROUP BY 
PP.PRODUCT,PP.START_TIME,PP.END_TIME,PP.PLANT_QTY
```

or

```
SELECT
  PP.PRODUCT  
  ,PP.START_TIME 
  ,PP.END_TIME  
  ,PP.PLANT_QTY AS PLANED 
  ,ISNULL(PAD.ACTUAL,0) AS ACTUAL
FROM
PRODUCT_PLAN AS PP
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS ACTUAL
    FROM PRODUCT_ACTUAL_DETAIL AS PAD
    WHERE  PP.PRODUCT = PAD.PRODUCT
        AND PP.START_TIME<=PAD.WORKING_TIME
        AND PP.END_TIME>=PAD.WORKING_TIME
)PAD
```

The result set :

```
PRODUCT START_TIME  END_TIME    PLANED  ACTUAL
PRODUCT1    2015-05-12 06:00:00.000 2015-05-12 07:00:00.000 5   3
PRODUCT1    2015-05-12 07:00:00.000 2015-05-12 08:00:00.000 3   2
```